# is there a way to translate data from SSAS OLAP cube into JSON format?

Tags: json, json.net, ssas

We have an SSAS OLAP cube built for a typical MS BI purposes.
Recently, we have discovered a great visualization power of d3.
Now, we are interested in presenting the cube data with d3, dc, crossfilter.
Is there a way to query SSAS cube in a background, and translate the results into an array of JSON objects, which could be served to d3/dc.js

Answer (score 0):

You can [expose your SSAS cube as an HTTP endpoint in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0).

Once you've configured that, you can use [Tedious](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/getting-started.html) to connect to your SSAS instance, pass queries, and return results. And then you'll have to wrap those results in some sort of JSON parser to make it play nice with d3.